# Permanent integration of LinkedIn, twitter in website/app

Tags: twitter, oauth, integration, linkedin-api

How we can permanently integrate LinkedIn, twitter in `website/app` using `OAuth`.

Once user connected to app using `OAuth` then he'll never ask again for `OAuth` connection even he change his password for **LinkedIn** later.

Like integration of `Facebook <->Twitter`:

Once we connect twitter account with facebook it automatically post on twitter when we post at facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "permanent", but once you've successfully authenticated the user, you'll have their access token and secret which can be used to make authenticated API calls to LinkedIn on their behalf. You should store this token/secret to make future calls.

Note: this token is only valid for 60 days, however (similar to Facebook). You'll need to refresh the token before 60 days, otherwise the user will need to be presented with the OAuth login dialog again to essentially re-auth your application.

This documentation goes into detail and provides code samples: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how we can refresh token if user not visited for 60 days?